# SQL connections dangling: Where am I not correctly closing up connections correctly?

Tags: java, mysql, connection, try-with-resources

I am building a basic java application to load some files into a mysql database. I am able to load the files up and populate my tables without any problems. However after speaking to someone who reviewed my code, I am apparently not correctly closing my connections and wasting resources. Where am I not closing up the connections?  Have I done this incorrectly?

I am using the try-with-resources construct within my **DbSinger** class to execute prepared statements to my database, which should automatically close the connection so long as the AutoCloseable interface is implemented, which it is in the parent class of **Db**. The *close()* method however is never reached. The **DbSinger** is instantiated inside my *main()* and then runs it's single method *populateSingers()* with an ArrayList of **Singer** objects.

**Connection Class**

```
public class SQLConnection {
    private static final String servername = "localhost";
    private static final int port = 3306;
    private static final String user = "ng_user";
    private static final String pass = "ng";
    private static final String db = "ng_music";
    private static final String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://" + servername + ":" + port + "/" + db;

    public Connection provide() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

            return DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, user, pass);

        }
        catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new SQLConnectionException(e);
        }
    }

    public class SQLConnectionException extends RuntimeException {
        SQLConnectionException(Exception e) {super(e);}
    }
}
```

**Abstract parent class**

```
public abstract class Db implements AutoCloseable{
    private Connection connection;

    Db() {
        SQLConnection sqlC = new SQLConnection();
        this.connection = sqlC.provide();
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() throws SQLException {
        if(connection != null) {
            connection.close();
            connection = null;
            System.out.println("Connection closed");
        }
    }
    Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;

    }
    boolean checkIfPopulated(String query){
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            return !rs.next();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Concrete class to execute queries to database for singers table**

```
public class DbSinger extends Db {
    public DbSinger() {
        super();
    }

    public void populateSingers(ArrayList<Singer> singers) {
        String populateSingersQuery = "insert into ng_singers(name, dob, sex) values(?,?,?)";
        if(!checkIfPopulated("select * from ng_singers")){
            System.out.println("Singer Table is already populated");
            return;
        }
        try (PreparedStatement ps = getConnection().prepareStatement(populateSingersQuery)) {
            for (Singer s : singers) {
                ps.setString(1, s.getName());
                ps.setDate(2, java.sql.Date.valueOf(s.getDob()));
                ps.setString(3, s.getSex());
                ps.addBatch();
            }
            ps.executeBatch();
            System.out.println("Singers added to table");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

My code is able to execute is able to run fine and does what it needs to, but I want to understand why and where I am not closing connections, and to understand how I can resolve this. Or at least understand if I am approaching this wrong.

Comment: Please show the code of instantiating `DbSinger`. Also, you are not closing `PreparedStatement` in `checkIfPopulated` method

Comment: Sure thing! 

`public static void main(String[] args) {
        start();
    }

    public static void start()  {
        DAO dao = new DAO();
        DbSinger dbSinger = new DbSinger();
        dbSinger.populateSingers(dao.loadSingers("data/ng_singers.txt"));  
    }`
The DAO class and _dao.loadSingers_ just returns an ArrayList of Singer objects.

I thought by using try-with-resources I wouldn't need to close the connections every time? But if that is not the case then I will close them off manually

Comment: Put that code in your question and have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you need to instantiate DBSinger class in `try-with-resources` statement to close the underlying connection.

Instead of doing:

```
DbSinger dbSinger = new DbSinger();
```

You need to do:

```
try (DbSinger dbSinger = new DbSinger()) {
// Your other code
}
```

This way the `close()` method you are overriding in your `Db` class will be called automatically.

Also, close the `preparedStatement` you created in your `checkIfPopulated` method by:

```
try (PreparedStatement ps = getConnection().prepareStatement(query)) {
// Other codes
}
```

Comment: Ahh right I understand now! Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is old way. And you do need close manually. However, with Java 8, you can use `try with resource` like below,

```java
 try (Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
    try {
       stmt.execute(dropsql);
   } catch (Exception ignore) {} // ignore if table not dropped
   stmt.execute(createsql);
   stmt.execute(insertsql);
   try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectsql)) {
     rs.next();
   } catch (Exception e2) {
     e2.printStackTrace();
     return("failed");
   }
 } catch(Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   return("failed");
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Forgive me if I'm not quite understanding but I don't see how your example is that much different? Within the `try` you are getting the connection and then creating a statement from that connection, and then executing it within the body and catching any exceptions. My code is doing roughly the same thing, expect the connection is already created in the parent class. Is it the best way to create a new connection within each try-with-rescources?

Comment: No. The difference is that it will close resource automatically for you.